# Displaying association rules in GUI in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, apriori

I have created association rules using the function apriori from the package arules. 
I have also created a GUI using RGtk2 package.
Now I have created a dialog box and I wish to display the rules in them.
By using the inspect command, I can display the rules in the console. 
Any idea how to display the rules in my interface?